# Java how to synchronize 2 threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

SOLVED !

I have a homework. I will say shortly what is about. I have to read from `.txt` file few numbers, and multiply them. I need to use threads and synchronize that multiplication only. I done that already and my homework ends here! But, I want to go ahead and create a more complex way for example:

I have in `.txt` numbers like this: 5, 6, 2, 11, 24, 10,
and then I multiply them like this 5*6*2*11*24*10 .

How can I create 2 threads, `Thread #1` for numbers, and `Thread #2` for multiply, and print them in console like this:

```
Thread #1 running, number is 5
Thread #2 running, multiply is 5
Thread #1 running, number is 6
Thread #2 running, multiply is 30
Thread #1 running, number is 2
Thread #2 running, multiply is 60
```

I really appreciate any suggestion, past 10 h since I work at this and still can't get it work.

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    Thread thread;

    MyThread(String name) {
        thread = new Thread(this, name);
    }

    public synchronized void numbers(boolean running) {
        if (!running) {
            notify();
            return;
        }
        notify();

        try {

            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("in.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
            String line;
            int numbers = 0;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] splitter = line.split("\\s");
                numbers = Integer.parseInt(splitter[0]);
                for (int i = 0; i <= splitter.length - 1; i++) {
                    numbers = Integer.parseInt(splitter[i]);
                    System.out.print("\nIn " + thread.getName() + "number is " + numbers + "\t");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("main thread interrupted");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("main thread interrupted");
        }
    }

    public synchronized void multiply(boolean running) {
        if (!running) {
            notify();
            return;
        }
        notify();

        try {
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("in.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
            String line;
            int numbers = 0;
            int multiply = 1;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] splitter = line.split("\\s");
                numbers = Integer.parseInt(splitter[0]);
                for (int i = 0; i <= splitter.length - 1; i++) {
                    numbers = Integer.parseInt(splitter[i]);
                    multiply = multiply * numbers;
                    System.out.print("\nIn " + thread.getName() + " multiply is " + multiply + "\t");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("main thread interrupted");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("main thread interrupted");
        }
    }

    synchronized public void run() {
        if (thread.getName().compareTo("Thread #1 ") == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                this.numbers(true);
            this.numbers(false);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                this.multiply(true);
            this.multiply(false);
        }
    }
}
```

My code look like this:

In main I call like this:

```
  MyThread mt1 = new MyThread("Thread #1 ");
  MyThread mt2 = new MyThread("Thread #2 ");
  mt1.start();
  mt2.start();
```

At this moment , my output look like this:

```
In Thread #2  multiply is 5  
In Thread #1 number is 5    
In Thread #1 number is 6    
In Thread #2  multiply is 6  
In Thread #2  multiply is 30    
In Thread #1 number is 2    
In Thread #1 number is 11   
In Thread #2  multiply is 660   
In Thread #2  multiply is 15840  
In Thread #1 number is 24
```

Comment: _still can't get it work_ show us what have you tried and describe the problems that you have faced.

Comment: when I say that, I mean I have 637 code lines, between /* */, each 100 lines are failed trials.

Comment: That's great, but now describe more specific problems. Were there compilation errors or maybe exceptions in runtime or was the result wrong? Try to provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or use some pseudo code to present the algorithm. Show us at least one try to begin with.

Comment: Done, my code is here, and output of my code too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use one implementation for both tasks. I would suggest to create `ReadThread` that will read the input file and `MultiplyThread` that will wait for some event for example and multiply numbers. Also they will need to share some collection of the numbers (see [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) for example).

So `ReadThread` read a number from file, adds it to the queue. At the same time `MultiplyThread` waits for anything to appear in the same queue and when this happens multiply new number on the previous one. There is also will be improvements on the design, because without much effort we can replace `MultiplyThread` with let's say `AddThread` that will calculate sum of the numbers.

However your implementation trying to do both tasks in one class which highly increases complexity. Also try to get rid of `synchronized` and `Thread.sleep` statements, in your case they will decrease the performance and there would be no point in using multithreading.

Here is example implementation for the method I've suggested.

First is the `ReadThread`. It has the queue that will contain numbers that have to be processed. I have simplified the reading of the numbers from the file, you can replace it with you reading implementation.

```
class ReadThread implements Runnable {

    private final String filename;
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> queue;

    public ReadThread(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> queue, String filename) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(filename);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fs);
            while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                int number = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println("ReadThread read " + number);
                queue.add(number);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the `MultiplyThread`. Here we take the number from the queue and multiply it on the `result` which stores the previous value. There is the problem with thread life cycle - we don't know when it should be stopped. So I have used simple `active` flag. Which tells the thread when to stop.

```
class MultiplyThread implements Runnable {

    private boolean active = true;
    private Integer result = 1;
    private final Queue<Integer> queue;

    public MultiplyThread(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (isActive()) {
            Integer number = queue.poll();
            if (number != null) {
                result *= number;
                System.out.println("MultiplyThread current result is " + result);
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        active = false;
    }

    public synchronized boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }
}
```

And here is the last part. It's more complex then yours, because of `MultiplyThread` interruption.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>();
    ReadThread readThread = new ReadThread(queue, "numbers.txt");
    MultiplyThread multiplyThread = new MultiplyThread(queue);
    Thread reader = new Thread(readThread);
    Thread multiplicator = new Thread(multiplyThread);
    multiplicator.start();
    reader.start();

    reader.join();
    multiplyThread.stop();
    multiplicator.join();
}
```

The result of the program

```
ReadThread read 1
ReadThread read 2
MultiplyThread current result is 1
MultiplyThread current result is 2
ReadThread read 3
MultiplyThread current result is 6
ReadThread read 4
MultiplyThread current result is 24
ReadThread read 5
MultiplyThread current result is 120
ReadThread read 6
MultiplyThread current result is 720
ReadThread read 7
MultiplyThread current result is 5040
```

You can see that thread are working concurrently, `ReadThread` does not wait `MultiplyThread` to calculate the result for all previous values.

Comment: Thank you very much @NikolayKondratyev for code and for explanation, I understood now !

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to do.  There are some obvious mistakes in the code which i want to highlight (and hence writing this answer), but I can't answer the question as the code seems to do what it was written to do: it runs 2 threads, both read from the same file and output results of reading in slightly different ways.

Now to the problems:

1) if you are extending Thread you should not have a thread field inside of it. Basically you can replace thread = new Thread(this ,name); with super(name).

2) your synchronized doesn't do anything.  Synchronized makes method enter a monitor (essentially acquire object lock) when you enter the method and release it when method is done.  Your two threads are 2 different instances which share no data between each other, so synchronizeds are not doing anything.

Comment: Thanks for advice @MK. It works now using the code above

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written your code, the two threads aren't really "connected", they don't share any memory. They read both the same file, but that's all - no shared memory. From what I guess, the idea would rather to have a "producer" thread which reads data from the file, and a "consumer" thread which get data read by the first thread and execute the multiplication. The second thread should not read the file.

You could write something with a shared AtomicInteger: when empty (null), the "producer" thread set it to what it has read ; and when non empty, the "consumer" thread read it, reset it to empty, and can run its multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Joel :), problem solved .